# Dnf has utf-8 problems

Tags: fedora, dnf

I have problem with dnf. Specifically: I cannot update my box anymore.

```
# dnf update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:11 ago on Thu Jun  2 14:32:01 2016.
Dependencies resolved.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/dnf", line 58, in <module>
    main.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 174, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 60, in main
    return _main(base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 120, in _main
    ret = resolving(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 142, in resolving
    base._plugins.run_resolved()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf/plugin.py", line 82, in fn
    dnf.util.mapall(operator.methodcaller(method), self.plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf/util.py", line 183, in mapall
    return list(map(fn, *seq))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf-plugins/protected_packages.py", line 66, in resolved
    protected = set(get_protected_names())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf-plugins/protected_packages.py", line 38, in get_protected_names
    protected.extend(map(str.strip, conf_file.readlines()))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Inside `/etc/dnf/protected.d/` there's

- dnf.conf with just the string "dnf" inside.
- rpmfusion-free-release-23.noarch.rpm
- rpmfusion-nonfree-release-23.noarch.rpm

Inside `/etc/yum/protected.d/ there is just`systemd.conf` with "systemd" inside.

I have tried almost everything:
 - removing every repository one by one and cleaning everything
 - firing a bug on the official redhat platform for bug report (where they say that it is a bug that will be fixed in the next dnf-2 release.

do you have any new idea?

Comment: what files do you have in /etc/dnf/protected.d and /etc/yum/protected.d directories (post its content in the question, please, if possible)?

Comment: try `dnf --disableplugin=protected_packages update`